Create df from worksheets in exisiting excel workbook
I've been running a script for years that recently stopped working for me because "the xlwt package is no longer maintianed and will be removed from pandas" if it hasn't already been removed? The end error I'm receiving
is: "ValueError: No engine for filetype: 'xls'"
Bascially I have an existing excel workbook and I need to create dataframes for each worksheet. At the end I will need to recombine all worksheets back into a new workbook.
Here is what I've had that is no longer working...
df1 = pd.ExcelFile('Workbook1.xlsx')

Errror is occurring here:
for sheet in df1.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(df1,sheet_name=sheet)
    df.to_excel(f"{sheet}.xls",index=False)

#Create dfs from worksheets in workbook
df2 = pd.read_excel('sheet1.xls')
df3 = pd.read_excel('sheet2.xls')
df4 = pd.read_excel('sheet3.xls')




Here I manipulate my dfs



#Save dfs into one workbook
with pd.ExcelWriter("New Workbook " + time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") + ".xlsx") as writer:
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet1", index=False)
    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet2", index=False)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet3", index=False)


Is there a reason you're saving as .xls format (very deprecated), and then reading the data again from the newly saved file? read_excel can return a dictionary of DataFrames in one step.

This is just the method I've found that worked. I'm open to other/better suggestions

Use read_excel by itself, which returns a dictionary of DataFrames if reading multiple sheets.

I get an error there is no such file or directory when I attempt to save an excel sheet as a df through just pd.read_excel. I've done this with read_excel opening the workbook first and again when it's doesnt. Are you able to provide an example?

Pass the entire filepath to read_excel.

Sheetname=0 is the first sheet/tab in the workbook, sheetname=1 is the second sheet/tab, sheetname=2 is the third sheet/tab in the workbook
df2 = pd.read_excel('Workbook1.xlsx',sheet_name=0)
df3 = pd.read_excel('Workbook1.xlsx',sheet_name=1)
df4 = pd.read_excel('Workbook1.xlsx',sheet_name=2)

